# What are these white specks on my petunias?

Tags: leaves, bugs

My petunias have gotten these white specks on them. I can't tell if they are bugs or if it's just debris. Can anyone tell me what this is and how I get rid of them?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be aphids and their detritus - spray with neem oil, or use an insecticide that treats for aphids. If you choose a systemic insecticide, that should keep them away for up to a fortnight; if you use a contact insecticide, or something like neem oil spray, you will probably need to respray more often.

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting some insecticidal soap tonight. Do I need to worry about harming bees with that? Google seems to say no but I'm just not sure.

Comment: So long as you don't directly spray it on a bee, it'll be fine... try to spray at dusk to avoid beneficial insects, but bees don't usually visit petunias since most don't have any nectar for them.